# Does galvanized pipe thread fit with brass thread?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Does galvanized pipe thread screw into brass thread?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What sizes and types of galvanized/brass threads are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of pipe threads in the USA, then yes, all the threads are compatible regardless of the material the pipe is is made of.  Brass will thread into steel  etc. There are such things as running thread where the fittings will not tighten and there are left hand threads which are rare. A better explanation of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: Note that just because they will fit doesn't mean you should do it! Galvanic corrosion is a real thing

Comment: He did not say that he was using it for a liquid so I didn't address corrosion  or even eddy currents. He asked if they can be screwed together. My last sentence said that a better explanation of what you are trying to do would be helpful. my 2 cents

Comment: Best to try to get clarification _before_ answering. While common sense _should_ indicate that people will ask more questions, there's no guarantee common sense _will_ be applied. What if the OP want to use this for water and is going to end up with nasty corrosion issues very quickly? That reflects poorly on the site in general and you in particular for giving info _assuming_ things...